# latest eclipse luna square brackets are not working in editors / german keyboard

Tags: eclipse, editor, square-bracket

In the latest version of eclipse luna it is not possible to use square brackets in any editor.
I have a german keyboard and I don't want to switch to english layout.
Under preferences -> general -> keys it is not possible to find the key combination <kbd>altgr</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>altgr</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>.
I uninstalled emmet and freemarker, but this did not solve the problem.

Is there someone who has an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem .. but its easy enough to create a custom key stroke with Autohotkey <http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, i solved the problem.

I had to remove the standard hotkeys for 'previous edit point' and 'next edit point'.

This is done under `window - preferences - keys` and clicking `unbind command`

[image]

Then the brackets were no longer blocked.